# React.js ... is there a CDN for the ReactCSSTransitionGroup?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, cdn, reactcsstransitiongroup

I am teaching myself React.js.  For now, I am avoiding having to set up and use node.js, servers, etc. (I want to focus on front-end functionality first).  To avoid having to set up my own node server and worry about endpoints, etc., I have been using these CDNs:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.24.0/babel.js"></script>
```

These have worked great so far.  But now I am trying to use the React.JS CSS transition library.  I tried using cloudflare:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-transition-group/2.3.1/react-transition-group.js"></script>
```

But this is not working. This is the only cloudflare link I could find on the topic.

Is there a way to use

```
<ReactCSSTransitionGroup></ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
```

without having to set up my own node server?

I would like to be able to pull the library in from a web link.  Or if I could get the entire JavaScript file, I could simply put that file in the same folder and try to load from a local folder using:

```
<script src="ReactCSSTransitionGroup.js"></src>
```

It seems that there should be a way to use ReactCSSTransitionGroup without having to do npm, command line launch server, express, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This may come too late but just in case somebody else is looking, just like me.

As per https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/, the cdn is at https://unpkg.com/react-transition-group/dist/react-transition-group.js

And you can use <ReactTransitionGroup.Transition>...</ReactTransitionGroup.Transition>
or <ReactTransitionGroup.CSSTransition>...</ReactTransitionGroup.CSSTransition>, and the same goes for SwitchTransaction and TransitionGroup, to do the animation.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using Create React App https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app.

Bundling and tests all taken care of for you. Not the best way to learn about build processes, but it's very fast to get going and you get to install and import from npm. win win in my books.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion, but it will save you a lot of time and hassle if you learn npm and just add things like "ReactCSSTransitionGroup" etc. via npm.

Also Webpack + Babel are part of the build most React developers use.

Check out this article to get up and running: https://www.codementor.io/tamizhvendan/beginner-guide-setup-reactjs-environment-npm-babel-6-webpack-du107r9zr.